# how to copy file content and directory data from zip archive using php

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I am using php to open a zip file and read its content and then copy this content to some other location. I am stuck at one point that how to copy the file content(file is a json) and also have some images in other directories which I want to access.

```
$zip = zip_open(Input::file('file'));
$rzip = zip_read($zip);
$entr_open_zip = zip_entry_open($zip, $rzip, '');
if ($entr_open_zip) {
    return "hello";
    die;
} else {
    return "hi";
    die;
}
```

I have opened the file but don't know how to copy content or even how to open the directory and access files in that directory. Any help is appreciated. I will explain more if needed.Ignore the typos.

I have seen some questions related to it but not getting satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) in PHP have functions to handle .zip files. In your case to extract all contents to specific directory, [extractTo](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php) function can make help.

Sample Code:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: do i have to download extra file for it or it is in php itself

Comment: It's within Php Platform.

Comment: ok its compulsory to extract the data. actually I need to copy the files. how will I achieve that

Comment: It will extract all files while maintaining hierarchy  into given location.

Comment: I am using laravel and i want to access these directory from the function which is opening it . Should I extract it in any temporary directory

Comment: FatalErrorException in ImportProductController.php line 43: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ZipArchive' not found

Comment: You should use it with `\\`  as `\ZipArchive` instead of `ZipArchive`.

Comment: please tell me how to access these files and what is the best location to extract these.

Comment: FYI - Only Sir!